# Using ID string as a css property doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a bunch of divs that i'm using to dynamically change style with jquery.css().
The way I'm pulling the property is to return the div id of the container.

In this case, stylechange = "fontFamily" because that's the ID of the main container.

str = the value of the checked option.

I've console.log() and alert() to debug this, and i'm getting strings returned, and when i manually set the properties and values it works.

However, using variables as either the property or the value does not work, and I'm stumped.

Javascript:

```
var stylechange = "";
var str = "";
$("select").change(function(){
   stylechange = $("select option:selected").parents(".styleoptions").attr('id');
   str = $("select option:selected").text();
   $(".elementselected textarea").css({stylechange: str});
})
```

HTML:
This is the div

```
<div class="ui-draggable ui-resizable addeddiv elementselected absolute move" style="position: relative; display: block;">
   <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e" style="z-index: 90; display: block;"></div>
   <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s" style="z-index: 90; display: block;"></div>
   <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se" style="z-index: 90;"></div>
   <div class="removethis ui-resizable-handle absolute">X</div>
   <textarea type="textbox" class="addedtext"></textarea>
</div>
```

This is the HTML that the css gets the ID from

```
<div id="fontFamily" class="styleoptions" style="display: block; text-transform: capitalize;">
   <div class="optiontitle" style="text-transform: capitalize;">family</div>
   <div class="options" style="text-transform: capitalize;">
      <select style="text-transform: capitalize;">
         <option style="text-transform: capitalize;">palatino</option>
         <option style="text-transform: capitalize;">arial</option>
         <option style="text-transform: capitalize;">verdana</option>
         <option style="text-transform: capitalize;">times new roman</option>
      </select>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: We'll need to see some HTML, but from the looks of it, you forgot to put the `var` in front of `stylechange` to actually declare it as a variable. And `fontFamily` isn't a CSS property, but `font-family` is

Comment: That sounds like a horrible idea! Using CSS properties as ID's ?

Comment: I added the HTML, and I did declare the variables beforehand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code tries to set a css property called `stylechange`, which is not what you need, you wants to set the css property assigned to the variable `stylechange`

so you need to use

```
$(".elementselected textarea").css(stylechange, str);
```

Or

```
var style = {};
style[stylechange] = str;
$(".elementselected textarea").css(style );
```